# Authorization code malformed or invalid when getting Azure AD access token with Spring

Tags: spring, azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, adal

I have this error when I try to generate the token.
I have do this tutorial http://blog.xebia.in/index.php/2017/12/21/spring-security-and-oauth2-with-azure-active-directory/.
My problem is when I try to get an access token after I have the code.
I have this error:

[image: Error in log]

Here is the related code:

```
 public AuthenticationResult getAccessToken(AuthorizationCode authorizationCode, String currentUri) throws Throwable {
    String authCode = authorizationCode.getValue();
    ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
    AuthenticationContext context = null;
    AuthenticationResult result = null;
    ExecutorService service = null;
    try {
        service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        context = new AuthenticationContext(authority + tenant + "/", true, service);
       //here are the error
        Future<AuthenticationResult> future = context.acquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(authCode, new URI(currentUri), credential, resource, null);
        result = future.get();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        throw e.getCause();
    } finally {
        service.shutdown();
    }
```